# How to delete <tabsize> spaces when pressing backspace in emacs?

Tags: emacs, whitespace, spaces

I have a mode (`vala-mode`) whose default is to use tabs, which is not the case with the projects I’d like to contribute to.

So I set `indent-tabs-mode` to `nil` and it seems to work just fine.

But now pressing backspace on the end of an indentation deletes space‑by‑space; is there a way to configure it to delete a number of spaces corresponding to the set `tab-width`?

Comment: Intelligent backspace like that is usually mode-specific. Assuming your `vala-mode` is the same as [this one](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Emacs?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=vala-mode.el) I don't see any support for it.

Answer (score 0):

Bind `DEL` to `backward-delete-char` instead of `backward-delete-char-untabify`.

For example, to replace one by the other globally, for all of its key bindings:

```
(define-key global-map [remap backward-delete-char-untabify] 'backward-delete-char)
```

Or just bind `backward-delete-char` to `DEL` or another key in particular modes.

Give it a try, to see if you really prefer that behavior.  Most users do not.

Comment: Both do the same for me, since .vala-files (in my case) only use spaces.

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev: Thanks for correcting the misplaced-`global-map` typo.